Are deficits and devaluation good or somehow benefit the capital owners or investors who buy bonds?
In Nial Ferguson's The Ascent of Money, when he is talking about one of the many Argentinian economic messes during the last century, he mentions something that I find pretty weird:
Owners of capital were attracted to deficits and devaluation;
Ferguson, Niall. The Ascent of Money: A Financial History of the World: 10th Anniversary Edition (English Edition) (p. 103). Penguin Publishing Group. Edición de Kindle.
I cannot understand why they would benefit from this, as for all I know there's a great risk of default on the part of the Argentinian government. I assume they were misled and didn't know how the situation would turn out.
